# Install dmg package on MAC OS from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, dmg

I would like to install the dmg java package in my MAC OS through the terminal

I tried using this command:

```
sudo installer -package jdk-7u51-macos-x64.dmg -target /
```

But I receive this error:

```
installer: Error the package path specified was invalid: 'jdk-7u51-macos-x64.dmg'
```

Comment: It looks like you are in the wrong directory - i.e. not where the package is. Type "ls" and see if you can see the package in the directory.

Comment: If you need to change directory to your Desktop, type "cd Desktop" then install.

Comment: I'm in the same folder than my file

Comment: If I extract the pkg package, then my command works well. But I would like to find a way to do it directly...

Comment: I think the installer expects a file ending in ".pkg" not a disk image that ends in ".dmg". I think you must mount the disk image by double-clicking it first.

Comment: Exactly. The command is `hdiutil attach` to mount the disk.

Comment: Once you have mounted/attached the disk, it will appear in the filesystem under `/Volumes/<diskname>`.

Comment: Duplicate found outside SO http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/is-there-a-command-to-install-a-dmg

Comment: You can't install a dmg; a dmg is like an iso, and does not specify its contents. The contents of a disk image can possibly be installed, if they are something that is installable.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
MOUNTDIR=$(echo `hdiutil mount jdk-7u51-macos-x64.dmg | tail -1 \
| awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'` | xargs -0 echo) \
&& sudo installer -pkg "${MOUNTDIR}/"*.pkg -target /
```

Comment: @SebMa I have `10.13.5 Beta (17F45c)` installed and this `awk` still works for me, even with spaces in mounted dir.

Comment: Does your `awk` command also return your mounted dir when there is no space in it ?

Comment: Because `$2` is equal to `Apple_HFS` in my case. Full output:
`/dev/disk2s2         Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/Lemur Installer`

Comment: That's a [useless `echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) with some additional pesky overcomplications. You want simply `MOUNTDIR=$(hdiutil mount jdk-7u51-macos-x64.dmg | awk 'END {$1=$2=""; print $0}')` (though you should properly also avoid using all uppercase for your private variables).

Answer (score 2):

Let `dmgFilePath` be the variable containing the path of your `dmg` file.

Then you can try this :

```sh
$ MOUNTDEV=$(hdiutil mount $dmgFilePath | awk '/dev.disk/{print$1}')
$ MOUNTDIR="$(mount | grep $MOUNTDEV | awk '{$1=$2="";sub(" [(].*","");sub("^  ","");print}')"
$ sudo installer -pkg "${MOUNTDIR}/"*.pkg -target /
$ hdiutil unmount "$MOUNTDIR"
```

Tested on macOS High Sierra even if `"$MOUNTDIR"` contains one space.

Comment: It won't work if the mounted directory have spaces, for example: `/Volumes/Lamur Installer`. I get `Installer` instead.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I had forgotten to mention the day I edited it according to your comment, I had fixed the space issue. It should work with space in the mounted directory

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem and found the root cause.
if you trying to install a package where the installer has no permission to access the directory you will get that weird error.

i.e

```
osascript -e {'do shell script "installer -allowUntrusted  -pkg ~/Download/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_8u275b01.pkg  -target /tmp/ " with administrator privileges'}

1:150: execution error: installer: Error - the package path specified was invalid: '/Users/user-x/Download/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_8u275b01.pkg'. (1)
```

either by moving the package into /tmp/ or change the directory permission so applescript or installer command can access the file.

```
osascript -e {'do shell script "installer -allowUntrusted  -pkg /tmp/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_8u275b01.pkg  -target /tmp/ " with administrator privileges'}     
installer: The upgrade was successful.K
```

Answer (score -2):

Thank Mateusz Szlosek,

For me :

```
$ MOUNTDIR=$(echo `hdiutil mount /Users/valorisa/Downloads/VirtualBox\ 5.0.14\ Build\ 105127
/VirtualBox-5.0.14-105127-OSX.dmg | tail -1 | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'` | xargs -0 echo) 
&& sudo installer -pkg "${MOUNTDIR}/"*.pkg -target /

Password:
installer: Package name is Oracle VM VirtualBox
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
```

Valorisa

Comment: please explain more